# what is the difference between fspecial('laplacian') and del2 matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In applying the laplacian to an image,What is the difference between

```
fspecial('laplacian', alpha)
```

and

```
L = del2(U)
```

Do they do the same operation on image?

Comment: @AnderBiguri the fspecial('laplacian', alpha)  gives me a white image(values are close to eachother when i use imshow) but del2 is not , but i dont know the inner difference , i mean they are supposed to be the same ,right ?

Comment: @SaraS Just in case you want to know even more, I had to extend the answer that you already accepted.

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks so much for your help , i really appreciate ur efforts :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except for a factor of 4 (del2 is only one fourth of the laplacian for 2D images) they are both approximating the Laplacian. They are both using a 3x3 filter, however the edges are treated differently. They use exactly the same filter for parameter `alpha` in `fspecial` set to 0. For all other values of the paramter `fspecial` will deliver a more smooth estimate of the Laplacian which is important in cases of noisy images.

Example:

```
[xi, yi] = ndgrid(1:10, 1:10);
data = xi.^2 + yi.^2 + rand(10);
a = 4 * del2(data);
alpha = 0;
b = imfilter(data, fspecial('laplacian', alpha),'replicate');
sum(sum(abs(a(2:end-1,2:end-1)-b(2:end-1,2:end-1))))
```

gives

> ans = 7.061e-13

`del2` is about 4 times faster because of lower overhead and behaves better at the borders. `fspecial` with parameter `alpha` set to 0 is not very smooth. For very noisy data `alpha` closer to 1 might be desired. Noisy numerical derivatives is a topic for itself.

Comment: See the sources of del2 and fspecial with ctrl.+d in the editor and you see what they are doing.

Comment: @rayryeng Please check the extended answer now. I even hadd to add a bit of information. :)